# Tables aren't showing up when I run migrate using Django and Heroku

Tags: python, django, postgresql, heroku, psql

I have a Django project with some models. I ran `python manage.py makemigrations` locally, added the migrations file to the master branch, then pushed to heroku. Then when I run `heroku run python manage.py migrate`, the migration completes successfully. However, when I connect to the database, none of my tables are there.

Here's a screenshot of what I did:

[image: steps]

What's going on here? Thanks!

Comment: Please show the DATABASES value in your settings.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Yup, the `DATABASES` value wasn't set correctly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to change the `DATABASES` value in my `settings.py` to:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': '<database_name>',
        'USER': '<user_name>',
        'PASSWORD': '<password>',
        'HOST': '<hostname>',
        'PORT': '5432'
    }
}
```